# List of list (multi dimensional array) into pandas Data Frame column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multidimensional-array

Having a multi dimensional array, and I want to introduced as a column into a df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B'], columns=['First'])
```

Initial df:

```
  First 
0     A 
1     B
```

Final output should be:

```
  First  Second  
0     A   [1,2,3]
1     B   [4,5,6]
```

The final obj is to upload the table into a data base, and I understand is not the best way to keep records. 
If you have any recommendations are more than welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: `df['second'] = [v for v in x]` or `df['second'] = list(x)`...

Comment: list(x) did the trick thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can directly [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the array `x` by unpacking its rows into a list:

```
df.assign(second=[*x])

   First  second
0     A  [1, 2, 3]
1     B  [4, 5, 6]
```

---

Note that, as mentioned in the comments this is the same as:

```
df.assign(second=list(x))
```

Comment: Let me add some details... @yuca

Comment: so is this a short hand for list comprehension? I get that you're calling a list over the contents of x, just wondering about the more technical detaiils

Comment: @Yuca same as `df.assign(k=list(x))`

Comment: Not really @yuca , `[*x]` is creating a list from the ndarray, which can then be assigned as new rows on df[`second`]

Comment: @anky_91 literally the same or equivalent?

Comment: Yes exactly @anky

Comment: Its just a fancy way of creating a list @yuca

Comment: my 'Second' column is a variable name since I have to add several columns. I can use df[var] = list(x) but is it possible with .assign()

Comment: @AlexSB `df.assign(**{var:list(x)})` ? similar `df.assign(**{var:[*x]})`

Comment: yes, that worked. however is it better than df[var] = list(x)? What is the advantage of using .assign() here

Comment: None its the same really @alex

Comment: @AlexSB except if you want to chain other operations (assign lets you do that), since `assign()` returns a copy whereas `df[var]=..` is an inplace operation

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['Second']=x.tolist()
print(df)

  First     Second
0     A  [1, 2, 3]
1     B  [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)
 df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B'], columns=['First'])
 df['second'] = [i for i in x] or df['second'] = list(x)
 print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this will extend the length of table , I still recommend `explode` it 
, after `groupby` you can always convert it back.

Object data type in single columns will disable most of db query functions and `pandas` functions

```
df.assign(list=x.tolist()).explode('list')
Out[6]: 
  First list
0     A    1
0     A    2
0     A    3
1     B    4
1     B    5
1     B    6
```